# what is the use of territory object on opportunity

Tags: opportunity, territory-management, territory

Can anyone help me to know what is the use of territory object on opportunity with a example. Please provide me some example and how there 2 objects are related to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Territories are a function of sales organization, and provide a way to split up the accounts that an organization's sales team will sell to. Typical types of territory splits would be based on geography, industry and company size.

In Salesforce, the Territory object will allow you to organize your Account, Contacts and Opportunities into the different territory buckets as defined by your organization. For example, if your organization decided to use geographically-based territories, your assignments may look something like the following:

- North East United States - Sales Rep A
- South East United States - Sales Rep B
- Central United States - Sales Rep C
- Western United States - Sales Rep D
- South America - Sales Rep E
- EMEA - Sales Rep F

You can use the Territory object in Salesforce to manage these assignments, as well as the subsequent records within your org. The [Getting Started with Territory Management guide](http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_implementing_territory_mgmt2_guide.pdf) is a great resource to help you to understand Salesforce Territory Management better.